# I need someone explain the idea & algorithm about Password Generator problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Password Generator
Write a programme, which generates a random password for the user. Ask the user how long they want their password to be, and how many letters and numbers they want in their password. Have a mix of upper and lowercase letters, as well as numbers and symbols. The password should be a minimum of 6 characters long.

Comment: Please note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on Stack Overflow; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, including relevant code, input, expected output, actual output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use : `pip install random-password-generator` and install library.

```
 pwo = PasswordGenerator()

  # It takes two arguments
  # required characters and length of required password
  pwo.shuffle_password('sdafasdf#@&^#&234u8', 20)

  pwo.excludeuchars = "ABCDEFTUVWXY" # (Optional)
  pwo.excludelchars = "abcdefghijkl" # (Optional)
  pwo.excludenumbers = "012345" # (Optional)
  pwo.excludeschars = "!$%^" # (Optional)
```

More info in this [link](https://pypi.org/project/random-password-generator/)  or [this](https://pynative.com/python-generate-random-string/)